# Parse xml with nested lists

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to parse a xml file in an object

This is my xml file named Changelog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Changelog>
  <Releases>
    <Release>
      <Version>1507</Version>
      <Date>22-11-2013</Date>
      <Changes>
        <Change>Change1</Change>
        <Change>Change2</Change>
        <Change>Change3</Change>
        <Change>Change4</Change>
      </Changes>
    </Release>
    <Release>
      <Version>1506</Version>
      <Date>20-11-2013</Date>
      <Changes>
        <Change>Change1</Change>
      </Changes>
    </Release>
  </Releases>
</Changelog>
```

This is my Changelog object I want to cast the xml to

```
[XmlRoot()]
public class Changelog
{
    private List<Release> releases;

    public List<Release> Releases
    {
        get { return releases; }
        set { releases = value; }
    }
}

public class Release
{
    private string version;
    private string date;
    private List<ChangeItem> changes;

    [XmlElement]
    public string Version
    {
        get { return version; }
        set { version = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public List<ChangeItem> Changes
    {
        get { return changes; }
        set { changes = value; }
    }
}

public class ChangeItem
{
    private string change;

    [XmlElement]
    public string Change
    {
        get { return change; }
        set { change = value; }
    }
}
```

Here I read the file

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Changelog));
Changelog changelog = (Changelog)serializer.Deserialize(new StreamReader(@"changelog.xml"));
Releases = changelog.Releases;

foreach (Release release in Releases)
{
    string version = release.Version;
    string date = release.Date;
    List<ChangeItem> changes = release.Changes; // Has only 1 item
}
```

The problem is that there is only 1 object in the Changes list, altough I expect 4 for the 1507 release.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ChangeItem.Change property decorated with an `XmlElement` attribute. This means it becomes another element.

Thus the xml would need to look different.

To make it work, mark the property with the `[XmlText]` attribute.

Also, your `Release.Changes` needed to be decorated with a `XmlArray` and a `XmlArrayItem` attribute.

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Changelog
{
    private List releases;

    public List Releases
    {
        get { return releases; }
        set { releases = value; }
    }
}

public class Release
{
    private string version;
    private string date;
    private List changes;

    [XmlElement]
    public string Version
    {
        get { return version; }
        set { version = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; }
    }

    [XmlArray("Changes")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Change")]
    public List Changes
    {
        get { return changes; }
        set { changes = value; }
    }

}

public class ChangeItem
{
    private string change;

    [XmlText]
    public string Change
    {
        get { return change; }
        set { change = value; }
    }
}
```

I marked in bold what my changes were.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
[XmlElement]
public List<ChangeItem> Changes
{
    get { return changes; }
    set { changes = value; }
}
```

to

```
[XmlArray("Changes")]
public List<ChangeItem> Changes
{
    get { return changes; }
    set { changes = value; }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `XmlArrayItemAttribute` and the `XmlTextAttribute`. See my answer for full code.

Comment: @SynerCoder That's true, missed that. You'll also need to be aware that you may find issues with the date format if you try to deserialize it on a machine with a different localisation setting. If possible the date should be in yyyy-MM-dd format

Comment: No problem, he serializes the data as a string. Issue circumvented.